# Donot want show Magento home using htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.7

I want to redirect  home page to another page  using access, which is not  an magento page.But i want show all other pages of magento.
event:

```
example.com  redirect to example.com/index.html (which is not an magento page)
example.com/index.php  redirect to example.com/index.html (which is not an magento page)
```

but  i want to show other magento pages ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the directoryindex directive?

In htaccess you can put this at the top to specify your root index file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

And you can create a rule to redirect index.php to the main site like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [R=301,L]
```

Then that will be your default index page.