# How to link a specific store view in Magento from outside the store?

Tags: magento, view

I have Magento set up in a multi-language store so that every language has its own store view. I have an HTML landing page where users choose the language they want, and I want to link each store view from the landing page.

I need to create a URL for each specific view so that it can be accessed from the landing page (like my_magento_installation.com/spanish, etc.), outside of the Magento installation. That means that I can't use any core code to get the store view.

I noticed that this URL format:

```
http://www.my_magento_installation.com/?___store=view_name
```

...is shown in the URL bar after selecting a specific store view from the default dropdown in Magento. However, if I set up a link with this format from outside the Magento installation, it just redirects to the base URL (www.my_magento_installation.com)

Thanks in advance,

Pau

Answer (score -1):

Pul Vila,here the soap list using soap client of magento list ,for referece here `http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/miscellaneous/store.list.html`

after using htaccess write url of landing page...[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433203/donot-want-show-magento-home-using-htaccess-file`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433203/donot-want-show-magento-home-using-htaccess-file)